# Understanding the reasons behind Openmdao design

Tags: openmdao

I am reading about MDO and I find openmdao really interesting. However I have trouble understanding/justifying the reasons behind some basic choices.

1. Why Gradient-based optimization ? Since gradient-based optimizer can never guarantee global optimum why is it preferred. I understand that finding a global minima is really hard for MDO problems with numerous design variables and a local optimum is far better than a human design. But considering that the application is generally for expensive systems like aircrafts or satellites, why settle for local minima ? Wouldn't it be better to use meta-heuristics or meta-heuristics on top of gradient methods to converge to global optimum ?  Consequently the computation time will be high but now that almost every university/ leading industry have access to super computers, I would say it is an acceptable trade-off.
2. Speaking about computation time, why python ? I agree that python makes scripting convenient and can be interfaced to compiled languages. Does this alone tip the scales in favor of Python ? But if computation time is one of the primary reasons that makes finding the global minima really hard, wouldn't it be better to use C++ or any other energy efficient language ?

To clarify the only intention of this post is to justify (to myself) using Openmdao as I am just starting to learn about MDO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No algorithm can guarantee that it finds a global optimum in finite time, but gradient-based methods generally find locals faster than gradient-free methods.  OpenMDAO concentrates on gradient-based methods because they are able to traverse the design space much more rapidly than gradient-free methods.

   Gradient-free methods are generally good for exploring the design space more broadly for better local optima, and there's nothing to prevent users from wrapping the gradient-based optimization drivers under a gradient-free caller. (see the literature about algorithms like Monotonic Basin Hopping, for instance)
2. Python was chosen because, while it's not the most efficient in run-time, it considerably reduces the development time.  Since using OpenMDAO means writing code, the relatively low learning curve, ease of access, and cross-platform nature  of Python made it attractive.  There's also a LOT of open-source code out there that's written in Python, which makes it easier to incorporate things like 3rd party solvers and drivers.  OpenMDAO is only possible because we stand on a lot of shoulders.

Despite being written in Python, we achieve relatively good performance because the algorithms involved are very efficient and we attempt to minimize the performance issues of Python by doing things like using vectorization via Numpy rather than Python loops.

Also, the calculations that Python handles at the core of OpenMDAO are generally very low cost. For complex engineering calculations like PDE solvers (e.g. CFD or FEA) the expensive parts of the code can be written in C, C++, Fortran, or even Julia. These languages are easy to interface with python, and many OpenMDAO users do just that.

OpenMDAO is actively used in a number of applications, and the needs of those applications drives its design.  While we don't have a built-in monotonic-basin-hopping capability right now (for instance), if that was determined to be a need by our stakeholders we'd look to add it in.  As our development continues, if we were to hit roadblocks that could be overcome by switching do a different language, we would consider it, but backwards compatibility (the ability of users to use their existing Python-based models) would be a requirement.